# SPFX webpart is not working in IE 11 shows "Reflect is undefined"

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, spfx

SPLoaderError.loadComponentError]:
***Failed to load component "d3f77efb-4879-4fc1-80c2-69a784ee109e" (FaqWebPart). Original error: ***Failed to load entry point from component "d3f77efb-4879-4fc1-80c2-69a784ee109e" (FaqWebPart). Original error: 'Reflect' is undefined

***INNERERROR:
***Failed to load entry point from component "d3f77efb-4879-4fc1-80c2-69a784ee109e" (FaqWebPart). Original error: 'Reflect' is undefined
***CALLSTACK:

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, I'm using pnp js + React.

First of all add IE11 polyfill, you can find it here:
https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/concepts/polyfill/

Then enable ie11 mode (just if you are using pnp js)
https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/concepts/ie11-mode/

In the end import polyfill in tsx file (place it at the top it is important!):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import "@pnp/polyfill-ie11";
```

Comment: place it at the top it is important!!